# How to match string not surrounded by specific prefix and suffix with regex

Tags: regex, groovy, regex-lookarounds

I need to match strings (or chars) *not* surrounded by specific prefix and suffix with Groovy regex.

Requirements for string:

- not preceded by two or three { chars and 0 or unlimited spaces - `[\{]{2,3}\s*`
- not followed by 0 or unlimited spaces and two or three } chars - `\s*[\{]{2,3}`

A few examples:

```
blah string blah string blah <- two matches
string <- match
{{ string <- match
{{string} <- match
string }} <- match
{string} <- match
{{string}} <- no match
{{ string}} <- no match
{{{string }}} <- no match
{{{ string }}} <- no match
```

All I have so far is `(?<!\{{2})string(?!\s*\}{2,})` but it doesn't work as expected because:

- negative lookahead and negative lookbehind are not "and-ed" so e.g. `string }}` is not matched
- negative lookbehind has to have fixed lenght so I can't apply 0 to unlimited whitespaces on it

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem using Groovy regex?

Comment: Are you looking to capture string, or simply match (boolean response)?

Comment: I think it might be best to use `(\{*) *(string) *(\}*)` and simply count the chars in capture group 1 & 3 + apply your logic

Comment: @ctwheels I need to use that to replace all matching strings with different one (String.replaceAll)

Answer (score 0):

You can you a combination of regex and logic as shown below:

[See this code working here](https://tio.run/##ZU9BTsMwEDzbrxhyqOK2JBS1N4xUAYITH2h9CK2bRDJJFVsglJqvByeGKAkHWzuzM7O7aVWWH19Nc5QnqFwbcOwoiWO8J@aQgZJAmyov0mDpyrrGCHlgO@RrWI8GrS7NfJY@Ueo2800l2W8UpvWfpRg5@mF2vEmP636BnsGAooLS9r5IJu6smhKN63ucXd@oAjqq5FklB7lVKvyOw309ZyHc8wm@3ts5i5etl@SnMDe7lYiULFKThQxXHI7ZDJjLBVMR/yeazTDR3HGswFg3hrjejQD3moX7b8UieHjZvj4/PQYtXnfsRjixhVRaorNQYhm1TfMD)

```
def list = [
    // match 
    "string",
    "{{ string",
    "{{string}",
    "string }}",
    "{string}",

    // two matches 
    "blah string blah string blah",

    // no matches 
    "{{string}}",
    "{{ string}}",
    "{{{string }}}",
    "{{{ string }}}"
]

list.each {
    s -> println s.replaceAll(~/(\{*)( *)(string)( *)(\}*)/, {
        if(it[1].length() != it[5].length() || (it[1].length() == it[5].length() && it[1].length() <= 1 )) {
            it[0] = it[1]+it[2]+"CHANGED"+it[4]+it[5]
        } else it[0]
    })
}
```

#### Explanation

The regex `(\{*)( *)(string)( *)(\}*)` works by capturing each part as follows:

- `(\{*)` captures all instances of `{`
- `( *)` captures spaces (so that we can put them back)
- `(string)` captures the string (you don't really need to capture it, but it allows you to run tests on it or manipulate it if you want - e.g. making it uppercase)
- `( *)` same as previous space capture
- `(\}*)` captures all instances of `}`

The code logic loops over each item in `list` and runs it through our regex replacement function. The regex replace function tests the captures to ensure one of two of the following requirements are met:

1. Number of `{` doesn't equal the number of `}`
2. Number of `{` equals the number of `}`, but one or fewer `{` exists:

- This matches `{string}` or `string`, but not `{{string}}`

We then replace the string `it[0]` with the respective parts. You can modify this to your liking, but based on your original question, this seems to be the output you're seeking:

#### Output

I replaced `string` with `CHANGED`.

```
CHANGED
{{ CHANGED
{{CHANGED}
CHANGED }}
{CHANGED}
blah CHANGED blah CHANGED blah
{{string}}
{{ string}}
{{{string }}}
{{{ string }}}
```